# Copying row 1 from multiple columns in an excel sheet to a n number of rows using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a target sheet which I'm copying multiple columns to. This target sheet also has values in the first row of each column that need to be copied and pasted for each nth row for the columns I'm adding.

Example

I'm setting the value of the cell in n rows in columns A & D from an array in another workbook (this part I've got coded). Columns B, C, H, J all have a value in row 1 which needs to be copied into all the rows that I'm pasting values into for columns A & D.

[image: example of data]

I have variable numRows which I've used to count the number of rows I will be pasting.

What is the most efficient way to copy that 1st row for columns B, C, H, J into the n number of rows below? Sometimes the number of rows copied into the target sheet will be 15-50, sometimes it will be 5,000+. Also the number of columns in row 1 that have data to be copied is about 20 or so and across 6 sheets.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1:I1").Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End With
```

Proceed pasting your other data after the captions have been set.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. I didn't even think to paste my data after pasting the non changing text first. Thanks.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. I didn't even think to paste my data after pasting the non changing text first. Thanks. The only thing is that column A does not have any data in it yet. I will be pasting data in there.

Comment: If one of the answers on this page deserves to be recommended please mark it as "Selected".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Variatus's suggestion of copying the first row before pasting my other data. The way i copied was

targetSheet.Range("A9:AY9").AutoFill Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A9:AY" & numRows), Type:=xlFillCopy

where numRows I had from my other sheet that I was copying from.